# Does Cudnn support INT32 datatype?

Tags: types, integer, cudnn

Device: GeForce GTX 1080 with cuda10.
as the ref says, I set `CUDNN_DATA_INT32` for aDesc,cDesc, and the input data are all int32. [**float for HALF and FLOAT tensors, and double for DOUBLE tensors.**](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#four-D-tensor-descriptor) . but no discription for int data. so I tried int float and double datatype for alpha and beta with int32 input, all comes a cudnn error  `Error Number 9 CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`. Does cudnn support int data ? or how can I use it in a correct way.

```
cudnnStatus_t cudnnAddTensor(
cudnnHandle_t handle,
const void *alpha,
const cudnnTensorDescriptor_t aDesc,
const void *A,
const void *beta,
const cudnnTensorDescriptor_t cDesc,
void *C)
```

```
i!     handle: type=cudnnHandle_t; streamId=0x3870eb0;
i!     alpha: type=CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT; val=0.000000;
i!     biasDesc: type=cudnnTensorDescriptor_t:
i!         dataType: type=cudnnDataType_t; val=CUDNN_DATA_INT32 (4);
i!         nbDims: type=int; val=4;
i!         dimA: type=int; val=[1,3,3,3];
i!         strideA: type=int; val=[27,9,3,1];
i!     biasData: location=dev; addr=0x10b4e6de400;
i!     beta: type=CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT; val=0.000000;
i!     srcDestDesc: type=cudnnTensorDescriptor_t:
i!         dataType: type=cudnnDataType_t; val=CUDNN_DATA_INT32 (4);
i!         nbDims: type=int; val=4;
i!         dimA: type=int; val=[1,3,3,3];
i!         strideA: type=int; val=[27,9,3,1];
i!     srcDestData: location=dev; addr=0x10b4e6de600;
i! Time: 2020-03-07T11:01:42.852528 (0d+0h+0m+3s since start)
i! Process=17985; Thread=17985; GPU=0; Handle=0x394c180; StreamId=0x3870eb0.
```